# What is the proper flow to merge the previous state with the new state on a useState hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have this on my initial state:

```js
  let initialStoreState = {
    products: [],
    checkout: [],
    adding: false,
    loading: true
  }

  const [store, updateStore] = useState(initialStoreState)

  useEffect(() => {
    if(someValue) {
        // pay attention to this code below
        updateStore((prevState) => {
          return { ...prevState, checkout, loading: false }
        })
    }
  }, [someValue]}
```

So would you use it like that on `updateStore` or like this:

```js
// this is how I normally see it being used
updateStore({ ...store, checkout, loading: false })
```

Is there any difference or mutability issues in one or another?

Comment: I may suggest to go even further and employ `useReducer` which is [recommended](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) when updating an object with multiple sub-values.

Comment: A benefit of `useState` is that you can call it multiple times to have multiple state variables, such as `adding`, `loading`, `products`, etc. That doesn't always work, but here it may simplify things, especially for atomic values like `loading`. Something complex like  `products` you still have to merge the changes usually.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about whether to use the functional update or to use state value directly to update the state, in most cases updating the state directly will work.

```
// will work most of the times
updateStore({ ...store, checkout, loading: false })
```

But it is very easy to run into issues where the outdated state value will get captured as a result of a **closure**. The simplest example would be if the callback passed to a `setTimeout` or `setInterval` tries to update the state value directly it may not produce the expected result.

To fix the closure issue  we can use [`functional updates`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

```
// example from the current use case
updateStore((prevState) => {
    return { ...prevState, checkout, loading: false }
})
```

Here is an example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-dubinsky-0b3ph?file=/src/index.js) with a demonstration of the closure issue.

However, for your current use case [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) seems more appropriate and it is the suggested way of managing a state object with multiple sub-values.